# Change column name in edmx

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, edmx

How can I change the column name in the class generated by `.edmx`? Not for the view purpose, instead changed column names should be available in the controller, so that meaningful column names are available for developers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know your asking about edmx , but if you use the editor I know you can setup mapping to change column names to more readable names.  You click on the column then go to properties , or open the mapping window.  I would not recommend changing the edmx as it gets over written and you would just have to do it all over again.